# Selected season in laravel using carbon

Tags: php, html, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get list of seasons from 1980 to today, and if somebody has selected one of them it should be selected in frontend but I do not know how to make it selected. It is my code: Can you help me?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">@lang('main.season')</label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="season">
      @for($i = 1980; $i < \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y') ; $i++)
        <option @if($data->season == $i) selected @endif>{{$i}}/{{$i + 1}}</option>
        @endfor
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should do the job, what does $data->season contain exactly?

Comment: for example 2017/2018 as string

Comment: dump your **$data** variable and show us details

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this inside the `<select>`

```
@for ($i = 1980; $i < date('Y'); $i++)
    <option value="{{ $val = "{$i}/" . ($i + 1) }}"{{ $val === $data->season ? ' selected' : ''}}>{{ $val }}</option>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <select class="form-control" name="season">
            @foreach(range(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->year, 1998) as $year)
                <option @if(2000 == $year) selected @endif>{{($year-1)}}/{{$year}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```